The IEDA software cannot run the Vue project, and the IDEA shows that no executable file was found in $PATH
The path environment of the computer is in. zshrc, and the bin file path of the node has also been added to zshrc. The terminal can also view the version of the node, but the idea still shows no executable file found in the path
Run error 127
Env: node: No such file or directory
The process has ended with an exit code of 127
enter image description here
enter image description here

The error indicates that the process can't be run because the node executable can't be found in your $PATH. On UNIX systems the environment variables differ between GUI applications and within the terminal. Terminal environment is only available to applications started from the terminal.
To solve this problem, IDEA tries to load the terminal environment on startup.
Seems that it can't retrieve all needed stuff in your case for some reason. Please see the corresponding KB article for troubleshooting.
